# MySQL Optimization When Not All Columns Are Indexed

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, innodb

Say I have a table with 3 columns and thousands of records like this:

```
id # primary key
name # indexed
gender # not indexed
```

And I want to find "All males named Alex", i.e., a specific name and specific gender.

Is the naieve way (`select * from people where name='alex' and gender=2`) good enough here? Or is there a more optimal way, like a sub-query on name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have thousand of records, matching the name, with only few being actually males, the index on `name` is enough. Generally you should not index fields with little carinality (only 2 possible values means that you are going to match 50% of the rows, which does not justify using an index).

The only usefull exception I can think of, is if you are selecting name and gender only, and if you put both of them in the index, you can perform an `index-covered query`, which is faster than selecting rows by index and then retrieving the data from the table.

Answer (score 1):

If creating an index is not an option, or you have a large volume of data in the table (or even if there is an index, but you still want to quicken the pace) it can often have a big impact to reorder the table according to the data you are grouping together.

I have a query at work for getting KPIs together for my division and even though everything was nicely indexed, the data that was being pulled was still searching through a couple of gigs of table. This means a LOT of disc accessing while the query aggregates all the correct rows together. I reordered the table using `alter table tableName order by column1, column2;` and the query went from taking around 15 seconds to returning data in under 3. So the physical gathering of the data can be a significant influence - even if the tables are indexed and the DB knows exactly where to get it. Arranging the data so it is easier for the database to get to everything it needs will improve performance.

Comment: Only useful for MyISAM tables though, and takes place at a point in time; subsequent insert/updates will slowly fragment this order.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to have a composite index.

i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX <some name for the index> ON <table name> (name, gender)
```

Then the `WHERE` clause can use it for both the name and the gender.

Comment: Could be useful, but trying to avoid the overhead of an extra index. If there's only a handful of people matching any name, it seems excessive.

Comment: @mahemoff - Hard disk is quite cheap. Also if you chose those indexes careully they can be used on other queries as well.

Comment: Cost and complexity of clustering is high though, if you get to the point where all indexes won't fit on a single disk.